# Displaying array content anytime there is an item in the array no properly working in my React Project

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In this my project, I want the values checked to be displaying in front of the filtered applied but this is not working as expected. Anytime a box is checked, it display all the checked value and anytime a box is uncheck, it goes away automatically. Can someone please help me check what I'm doing wrong.  [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/mystifying-zhukovsky-vo8h7?file=/src/App.js:0-1374)

My App.js code

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [isselected, setisselected] = useState([]);

  const OnChange = (e) => {
    console.log(e.target.checked);
    const ischecked = e.target.checked;
    if (ischecked) {
      setisselected([...isselected, e.target.value]);
    } else {
      const index = isselected.indexOf(e.target.value);
      isselected.splice(index, 1);
      setisselected(isselected);
    }

    console.log(isselected);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(isselected, "value selected");
  }, [isselected]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <span>
        Filters applied:{" "}
        {isselected.map((i) => (
          <span>{i}</span>
        ))}
      </span>

      <div className="first-search">
        <input
          type="checkbox"
          className="input-1"
          value="Lastsevendays"
          name="last_seven"
          id="1"
          onChange={OnChange}
        />
        <label htmlFor="">Last 7 days</label>
      </div>

      <div className="first-search">
        <input
          type="checkbox"
          className="input-1"
          name="last24"
          value="last_24"
          id="2"
          onChange={OnChange}
        />
        <label htmlFor="">Last 24 hours</label>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Issue

You are mutating the `isselected` state when removing filters. `Array.prototype.splice` mutates the array in-place.

```
const OnChange = (e) => {
  const ischecked = e.target.checked;
  if (ischecked) {
    setisselected([...isselected, e.target.value]);
  } else {
    const index = isselected.indexOf(e.target.value);
    isselected.splice(index, 1); // <-- mutation!!
    setisselected(isselected);   // <-- same array reference
  }
};
```

## Solution

Use `Array.prototype.filter` to filter by index the `isselected` array and return a new array reference.

```
const OnChange = (e) => {
  const ischecked = e.target.checked;
  if (ischecked) {
    setisselected([...isselected, e.target.value]);
  } else {
    const index = isselected.indexOf(e.target.value);
    setisselected((isselected) => isselected.filter((_, i) => i !== index));
  }
};
```

Since the `isselected` array is storing primitives, you can filter directly by the filter value as well.

```
setisselected((isselected) =>
  isselected.filter((val) => val !== e.target.value)
);
```

[image: Edit displaying-array-content-anytime-there-is-an-item-in-the-array-no-properly-worki]

Answer (score 0):

what you're doing is that you are displaying the state with console.log() and it's the nature of console.log() that it shows the previuos value of the state,and also I did some changes in your Onchange function and it's working now try this and then let me know it's working or not:

```
     const OnChange = (e) => {
    console.log(e.target.checked);
    const ischecked = e.target.checked;
    if (ischecked) {
      setisselected([...isselected, e.target.value]);
    } else {
      let temp = [isselected];
      const index = temp.indexOf(e.target.value);
      temp.splice(index, 1);
      setisselected(temp);
    }

    console.log(isselected);
  };
```

Comment: `console.log` doesn't show the previous state, it's logging the state from the current enclosure, i.e. from the current render cycle. The logging of state hasn't anything to do with why the state wasn't updating correctly. If you want to shallow copy the `isselected` state first then the correct syntax would be `const temp = [...isselected];` otherwise you are placing an array in an array. Also, the `console.log(isselected);` would *still* log the stale state.